# How to Enable accessibility on Microsoft Teams using code

Tags: c#, accessibility, ui-automation, desktop-application, microsoft-teams

I am working on a desktop plugin which works on MS Teams desktop app. In short, this plugin is an overlay which sits on top on MS Teams app and tracks elements (eg. Chats, Calendar etc.). To track and find elements by plugin, accessibility settings must be enabled for MS Teams. This can be done manually by going to Accessibility Internals and enabling the below checkboxes (shown in screenshot below).

[image: Accessibility Internals > Global accessibility mode. Native accessibility API support checked. Web accessibility checked.]

Now the question is, how can I reliably do it from the code, preferably using C# code? Please comment if you need more details about the question.

Comment: If you ask a question and it gets closed you should instead edit the closed question rather than copy pasting it into a new question. Anyway, what happens if you pass the relevant `--force-renderer-accessibility` flag when Chrome is launched, does that not enable all the features? If so you just need to find a way to modify how MS Teams is launched to include that flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I edited original one but it is still closed for replies for some reason. Anyways I don't have control on Teams app launch as my plugin is on top of it and comes to action when teams is already launched. What I want is to enable accessibility when my plugin (C# code) is loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: Currently the Teams platform does not cover anything related to extending accessibility.

Comment: The accessibility window looks like being based on chromium, and I know a way to enable accessibility in Chrome programmatically which could help here as well. But I just can't find these settings in the current MS Teams app version, could you share the way how could I open it? And perhaps, your app version.